# how to convert a while loop into a recursive method in a specific situation

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop

I need help converting this while loop method to recursive method

```
public static int diaseneliminar(double cantidamedicina, double porcentajeaeliminar){
    double basedivisorporcentaje = 100;
    double cantidadmedicinarestante = cantidamedicina*(1-(porcentajeaeliminar/basedivisorporcentaje));
    int contadordia=0;
    while(cantidamedicina>cantidadmedicinarestante){
        cantidamedicina = cantidamedicina - (cantidamedicina * 0.2);
        contadordia++;
        System.out.println("cantidamedicina:"+cantidamedicina+"cantidadmedicinarestante:"+cantidadmedicinarestante+"contadordia:"+contadordia);
    }
    return  contadordia;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split it up in initialisation and the recursion, making the negation of the while-critearia to the return-criteria:

```
public static int diaseneliminarRecursive(double cantidamedicina, double porcentajeaeliminar){
    double basedivisorporcentaje = 100;
    double cantidadmedicinarestante = cantidamedicina*(1-(porcentajeaeliminar/basedivisorporcentaje));
    return recursion(0, cantidamedicina, cantidadmedicinarestante);
}

private static int recursion(int contadordia, double cantidamedicina, double cantidadmedicinarestante) {
    System.out.println("cantidamedicina:"+cantidamedicina+"cantidadmedicinarestante:"+cantidadmedicinarestante+"contadordia:"+contadordia);
    if(cantidamedicina<=cantidadmedicinarestante){
        return contadordia;
    }
    return recursion(++contadordia, cantidamedicina - (cantidamedicina * 0.2), cantidadmedicinarestante) ;
}
```

**TEST**

```
System.out.println(diaseneliminar(100, 80));
System.out.println(diaseneliminarRecursive(100, 80));
```

**Output original:**

```
cantidamedicina:80.0cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:1
cantidamedicina:64.0cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:2
cantidamedicina:51.2cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:3
cantidamedicina:40.96cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:4
cantidamedicina:32.768cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:5
cantidamedicina:26.2144cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:6
cantidamedicina:20.97152cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:7
cantidamedicina:16.777216000000003cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:8
8
```

**Output recursive**

```
cantidamedicina:100.0cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:0
cantidamedicina:80.0cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:1
cantidamedicina:64.0cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:2
cantidamedicina:51.2cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:3
cantidamedicina:40.96cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:4
cantidamedicina:32.768cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:5
cantidamedicina:26.2144cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:6
cantidamedicina:20.97152cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:7
cantidamedicina:16.777216000000003cantidadmedicinarestante:19.999999999999996contadordia:8
8
```